# Expected Behavior? No exception when referencing fields on null parent

Tags: apex

I was trying to retrieve `manager.Name` going up in hierarchy I also tried to retrieve `manager.manager.Name`. Field `manager.Name` was **null** so I was expecting it to throw an exception. However I didn't got any exception. 
I tried following code on **Developer** console:

```
List<User> userList = [Select manager.Name, manager.Mobile_number__c, manager.manager.Name, manager.manager.Mobile_number__c, manager.Email, manager.manager.Email, manager.manager.manager.Email from User where id = '005900000018D73'];

System.debug('1. :  '+ userList.get(0).manager); //if manager is getting NULL
System.debug('2. :  '+ userList.get(0).manager.manager); // NULL.manager is/should not possible ?! 
System.debug('3. :  '+ userList.get(0).manager.manager.manager);
```

What I was **expecting** that it should throw an **Exception**:

> Attempt to de-reference NULL object.

**Observation**: 
It runs successfully with no errors.

Can anyone explain why it's happening like this?

Comment: We have some hierarchy checks within our managed packages and we reference the 5 levels up without using null checks. Spent a day or two testing these scenarios and your results are right. Strange behaviour as opposed to what a developer would expect. Would love to hear an answer to this.

Comment: @TSmith Yes, I also found it strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_lookup.htm) about lookup relantionships.

I'm quoting:

> Beginning with API version 13.0, relationship SOQL queries return
>   records, even if the relevant foreign key field has a null value, as
>   with an outer join.

**Update**

Adding @IllusiveBrian's [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_field_relationships.htm) about accessing relationships.

Quote from this link:

> When being read as a value, if c.Account is null, then c.Account.Name
>   evaluates to null, but does not yield a NullPointerException.

Comment: I hope that one day those will be valid for process builder :)

Comment: Also related: [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_field_relationships.htm) (Check the second yellow box).  Even without SOQL, sObjects will not throw `NullPointerException` when read as a field on another object, unless you try to access their `Id`.